# Updating immutable data and returning a promise in Javascript

Tags: javascript, redux, immutable.js

So, I am building a React-Redux app using Immutable objects and I need to update my state with some data I fetch from an API endpoint.

Here is my state structure before I add in the data

```
    const state = fromJS({
        tickers: ['AAPL', 'TSLA', 'GOOGL'], 
        data: {
            AAPL: Map(), 
            TSLA: Map(), 
            GOOGL: Map()
        }
    });
```

The idea is that the data I fetch goes into the respective ticker keys in the data object

Here is the code where I try to fetch the data and update it

```
export function requestAPIData(state, tickerArray){
    return dispatch => {
        return  yahooFinance.historical({
                    symbols: tickerArray, 
                    from: '2012-01-01', 
                    to: '2012-01-05', 
                    period: 'd'
                }, (err, quotes) => {
                    throw new Error('err');
                }).then(result => {
                    addDataToKeysFunction(state, result);
                }).then(() => {
                    console.log(state);
                    dispatch(success());
                })
            }

        }

function addDataToKeysFunction(state, data){
    return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
        for(let key in data){
            console.log(data[key]);
            state.setIn(['data', key], data[key]);
        }
        resolve();
    })
}
```

So, here is what confuses me. If I just call state.setIn on the state object, it will only update temporarily because Immutable objects don't update until you return the state (?). But, I am also returning a promise that needs to be resolved or rejected. How do I ensure that the state gets updated and resolve the promise.

I am relatively new to dealing with Immutable data structures, so if there is something blatant I am missing, please do point it out. Also, if using a callback is the only way to get this done, that's fine as well.

Comment: I strongly suggest in investing a hour of your time to watch the free [Getting Started With Redux](https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux) videos found at redux.js.org (created by the creator of Redux). It really helps you think how you should reduce the immutable state instead of mutating it directly.

Comment: @jehna1 - Hey, yeah I've been through those videos, and I loved them. They are the main reason I decided to start using Immutable JS, because they make handling redux application data so much easier. However, they don't have any info regarding Immutable JS itself and the TypeScript documentation for Immutable doesn't help either.

Comment: I suggest you revisit the ones that talk about using a reducer to change the state.

Comment: @jehna1 - Any reason you think I should do that? Maybe the way I am writing my code?

Comment: Yes. To change state you should always have a reducer function that takes the state as an input and returns a new state.

Comment: But, that is what I have. I'm sorry, I'm just trying to figure out why exactly you think this is bad reducer composition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I figured out an answer. For some reason, returning the data as part of the resolve() of the promise call threw an error, but returning it in a callback works just fine.

```
export function requestAPIData(state, tickerArray){
    return dispatch => {
        return  yahooFinance.historical({
                    symbols: tickerArray, 
                    from: '2012-01-01', 
                    to: '2012-01-05', 
                    period: 'd'
                }, (err, quotes) => {
                    throw new Error('err');
                }).then(result => {
                    addDataToKeysFunction(state, result, function(return_data){
                        console.log(return_data);
                    });
                })
            }

        }

function addDataToKeysFunction(state, data, done){
    let new_state = state;
    for(let key in data){
        new_state = state.setIn(['data', key], data[key]);
        state = state.merge(new_state);
    }
    done(state);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code that appear to, frankly, demonstrate a fundamental misunderstanding of Redux. Like others have expressed before me I would recommend going back to and spending some time with the Redux documentation.

Some comments on your code above:

- Dispatch should only ever accept plain JS objects that communicate an intention to the store (and reducers by extension).
- Anytime your app mutates its state, that logic should occur inside its reducer. Here, you appear to be mutating state outside of the reducer.
- When you mix asynchronous actions with Redux, you should probably be using another library like Thunk. Check out the Redux documentation for async recipes.

Comment: Hey, okay so just to be clear on what exactly I need to clean up in my code

1) Dispatch is accepting a plain JS Immutable object, it makes an API call and then fills that data into the Immutable object. What is wrong with this approach? 
2) Are you referring to my use of a private function to add API data to the state? 
3) I am using Redux Thunk...

Comment: Hey, rereading this I was maybe a bit too harsh. If you post a link to a GitHub repo, I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: Also, dispatch is not accepting a plain JS object if it's accepting an immutable map.

Comment: Here you go https://github.com/redixhumayun/stock-market-tracker/tree/master/stock-server/src/reducer
That's the link to the reducer and reducer logic files. Thanks for taking the time out to take a look at it.